# javascript: split string by groups

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a **standard** function that does this:

Some examples:

```
"LLLDDDDLL" -> ["LLL", "DDDD", "LL"]
"LLLDDDD" -> ["LLL", "DDDD"]
"DDDDLL" -> ["DDD", "LL"]
```

Comment: Is that a homework? What attempts did you made to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this regex

`(\w)\1*`

This regex will match the continuously repeated character.

```js
function splitRepeated( input ) {
  let result = input.match(/(\w)\1*/g) 
  console.log( result )
}

splitRepeated("LLLDDDDLL")
splitRepeated("LLLDDDD")
splitRepeated("DDDDLL")
```

Comment: it should be input: "LLDDDLL" -> output: ["LL", "DDD", "LL"]
it can be solved with "LLDDDLL".split(regex) but i can't find regex